# When I try to create a new database in Management Studio I get this error message

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

When I try to create a new database in Management Studio, I get this error message

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express
>
> Cannot show requested dialog.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Cannot show requested dialog. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.SqlMgmt)
>
> Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)

Comment: Do you have any other version of SSMS installed?  Any version of the .Net management tools for SQL Server, or the SqlServer PowerShell module?  Have you applied the latest service pack?

Comment: No i don't have